# NextJS next-auth 500 Internal Server Error when trying to login (Netlify)

Tags: next.js, netlify, next-auth, sanity

When trying to login with next-auth, I get 500 from /api/auth/providers and "Internal Server Error" as the only message on the screen. This works great locally, but not in production. I use Netlify to host the project.

How do I fix these server issues?

packages:

- "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
- "next": "^13.2.4",
- "next-auth": "^4.20.1",
- "next-auth-sanity": "^1.4.8",
- "next-connect": "^1.0.0",
- "next-pwa": "^5.5.2",
- "next-sanity": "^4.1.5",
- "react": "^18.2.0",

Engine:

- "node": "18.x"

[image: Network messages]

Before trying to login, next-auth already recognizes that there's something wrong and suggests it's the `NEXTAUTH_URL` that's incorrect. This value is set as localhost:3000 in the local environment and https://my-domain.com in Netlify. The value is also set for all scopes. The same goes for the `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` value

[image: Errors from next-auth]

The login component looks like this and it fails in the try/catch. The adapter I'm using is Sanity CMS. Again, this works fine locally.

[image]

Lastly this is the `[...nextauth].js with the options.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I noticed that I accidentally added a "/" at the end of the `NEXTAUTH_URL` which caused the issue. I removed it and now it works both locally and in production.

tldr: `NEXTAUTH_URL="https://example.com/"` --> `NEXTAUTH_URL="https://example.com"`